# How to add a link in an item to open another dynamically added item in isotope?

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I am currently trying out David DeSandro's Isotope jQuery plugin: I'm adding items dynamically to the container.

I'm also using [the technique used in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/desandro/8QkEw/) that sorts a clicked item for top left of the container.

My Isotope items shall contain some text. Clicking a link within this text, another item shall be sorted for and placed top right, not the one clicked on.

How could I make a link `<a href="...` in one item to trigger sorting for top left of another item, knowing that these items are added dynamically?

Thanks a lot for your answers and thanks a lot to David De Sandro's work; I will for sure get a commercial license as soon as I can achieve this...

Comment: So 1. each and all Isotope elements contains a link somewhere 2. if a viewer clicks on such link, some other element (containing also a link) gets placed top left 2. every element can thus appear top left, but never through its own link being clicked. Is that the behaviour that you want?

Comment: If you generate your Isotope elements dynamically, inserting or appending them to the #container, you might want not to use an id, but rather set a data-attribute on each div like <div class="item" data-element="G">A <a href="#">link to element G</a></div> and evaluate the clicked div's attribute to cross-target another Isotope element. Just a thought...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks a lot, this gave me the missing idea (assigning an id to the link and to the divs). Here's the working example:

> http://jsfiddle.net/vpxavier/QRy9W/23/

Now I just have to manage adding ids dynamically. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If, according to my comment, I understood you right(?), the link you click on element A needs to set the .selected class on another element B, then invoke sortBy to move element B to the top left. That means you should assign the triggering click function **not** to the whole Isotope element A (as is usually the case), but only to the link contained inside of that element A. Then, not element A is sorted to the top left, but element B (and click on a link in E sorts P to the top left, G sorts W to the top left, and so forth). That could be a start:

You want cross-links between all elements like so, as far as I understand:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">A <a href="#" id="element-G">link to element G</a></div>
  <div class="item">B <a href="#" id="element-F">link to element F</a></div>
  <div class="item">C <a href="#" id="element-E">link to element E</a></div>
  ...
  ..
  .
</div>
```

And then you could [go forward with this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/djKBC/) where you can see that now you 1. sort the Isotope elements only by clicking on a link inside them and that 2. you can extract the id of another one of your Isotope elements - the one to be then classed with .selected to be sorted top left.